# Keep leading 0's when copying data from mysql to excel

Tags: excel

I am copying data from mysql database to excel. I have bunch of texts like :

0023,0043 etc but when I copy it to excel column it gets pasted as 23,43 etc. I tried to change the field type to text before copying the data but it does not work either. How do I retain the leading 0's when copying and pasting data to excel?

Comment: Are they always going to be 4 digits and you want to keep the leading 0s? also please confirm if you want to treat them as text or number in excel?

Comment: I found out that pasting while keeping source formatting works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEFORE pasting Highlight the column in question, right click to format cells, on the number tab choose text from list on left, click OK.

Also, If feasible, if you can insert a single quote (`'`) before the number, Excel should treat it as raw data.